# How to improve the performance of np.where (takes 98% time in line_profiler)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, search

I am doing a search of a value read from a file in a large dataframe using np.where and it takes 98% of the time. The code is taking like 19 hrs to run.

So this code scans through a dataframe containing 2 columns of around half million records with first column contains numeric and 2nd column contains text.
Now the workflow is that I read another file line by line and then search for 'alleleID' in the dataframe and extract some data from the dataframe once it matches. I am doing this using np.where code.

```
res = np.where(df['alleleID'] == alist[0])
```

This line takes around 98% in line_profiler. So, how do I improve this?

After researching I tried the df.loc after indexing but the problem I found is that every time I a searching for one alleleID read from the file and that is in a variable (alist[0]) and I cannot pass this variable to search using

```
res = df.loc(alist[0])
```

Because df.loc always expect a value and not a variable.

Would appreciate any help to improve the performance of this program.
Thank you.
Complete Code below:

```
with open('C:/Data/DATA/ClinVar/temp.dat', 'r') as varFile:
    count = 0
    dat1 = []
    dat2 = []
    dat3 = []
    dat4 = []
    dat5 = []
    dat6 = []
    dat7 = []
    dat8 = []
    dat9 = []
    dat10 = []
    dat11 = []
    dat12 = []
    dat13 = []
    dat14 = []
    dat15 = []
    dat16 = []
    dat17 = []
    dat18 = []
    dat19 = []
    dat20 = []
    dat21 = []
    dat22 = []
    dat23 = []
    dat24 = []
    dat25 = []
    dat26 = []
    dat27 = []
    dat28 = []
    dat29 = []
    dat30 = []
    dat31 = []
    dat32 = []
    dat33 = []
    dat34 = []
    dat35 = []
    dat36 = []
    dat37 = []
    dat38 = []
    dat39 = []
    dat40 = []
    for line in varFile:
        alist = line.split('\t')
        count += 1
        print(alist[0], "-", count)
        if(alist[1] == 'single nucleotide variant'):
            hgvs = '-'
            aaChange = ''
            otherID = '-'
            otherID1 = '-'
            uniProt = ''
            uniProt_var = ''
            omim_list = ''
            if alist[2] and not alist[2].isspace():
                hgvs = alist[2].split(' ')
                i = 0
                for i in range(0,len(hgvs)):
                    if(hgvs[i][0] == "("):
                        aaChange = hgvs[i]
            else:
                hgvs = '-'
            otherID = alist[28].split(',')
            j = 0
            omim = ''
            uniprot = ''
            hgmd = ''
            hbvar_list = ''
            uni_list = ''
            hgmd_list = ''
            flag1 = 0
            flag2 = 0
            flag3 = 0
            flag4 = 0
            flag5 = 0
            indices1 = [i for i, elem in enumerate(otherID) if 'OMIM' in elem]
            for b in range(0, len(indices1)):
                omim = otherID[indices1[b]].split(':')
                flag2 += 1
                if(flag2 == 2):
                    omim_list = omim_list+','+omim[1]
                    #print("OMIM_list",omim_list)
                else:
                    omim_list = omim[1]
            indices2 = [i for i, elem in enumerate(otherID) if 'HGMD' in elem]
            for b in range(0, len(indices2)):
                hgmd = otherID[indices2[b]].split(':')
                flag3 += 1
                if(flag3 == 2):
                    hgmd_list = hgmd_list+','+hgmd[1]
                else:
                    hgmd_list = hgmd[1]
            indices3 = [i for i, elem in enumerate(otherID) if 'HBVAR' in elem]
            for b in range(0, len(indices3)):
                hbvar = otherID[indices3[b]].split(':')
                flag4 += 1
                if(flag4 == 2):
                    hbvar_list = hbvar_list+','+hbvar[1]
                else:
                    hbvar_list = hbvar[1]
            indices4 = [i for i, elem in enumerate(otherID) if 'UniProtKB' in elem]
            for b in range(0, len(indices4)):
                otherID1 = otherID[indices4[b]].split(':')
                flag5 += 1
                if(flag5 == 2):
                    uni_list = uni_list+','+otherID1[1]
                else:
                    uni_list = otherID1[1]
            AF_ESP = ''
            AF_EXAC = ''
            AF_TGP = ''
            res = np.where(df['alleleID'] == alist[0])
            if res[0].size != 0:
                res1 = df['info'][res[0][0]].split(';')
                indices5 = [i for i, elem in enumerate(res1) if 'AF_ESP' in elem]
                for b in range(0, len(indices5)):
                    res2 = res1[indices5[b]].split('=')
                    AF_ESP = res2[1]
                indices6 = [i for i, elem in enumerate(res1) if 'AF_EXAC' in elem]
                for b in range(0, len(indices6)):
                    res2 = res1[indices6[b]].split('=')
                    AF_EXAC = res2[1]
                indices7 = [i for i, elem in enumerate(res1) if 'AF_TGP' in elem]
                for b in range(0, len(indices7)):
                    res2 = res1[indices7[b]].split('=')
                    AF_TGP = res2[1]
            alist[30] = alist[30].rstrip('\n')

            dat1.append(alist[0])
            dat2.append(alist[1])
            dat3.append(alist[2])
            dat4.append(hgvs[0])
            dat5.append(aaChange)
            dat6.append(omim_list)
            dat7.append(uni_list)
            dat8.append(hgmd_list)
            dat9.append(hbvar_list)
            dat10.append(alist[3])
            dat11.append(alist[4])
            dat12.append(alist[5])
            dat13.append(alist[6])
            dat14.append(alist[7])
            dat15.append(alist[8])
            dat16.append(alist[9])
            dat17.append(alist[10])
            dat18.append(alist[11])
            dat19.append(alist[12])
            dat20.append(alist[13])
            dat21.append(alist[14])
            dat22.append(alist[15])
            dat23.append(alist[16])
            dat24.append(alist[17])
            dat25.append(alist[18])
            dat26.append(alist[19])
            dat27.append(alist[20])
            dat28.append(alist[21])
            dat29.append(alist[22])
            dat30.append(alist[23])
            dat31.append(alist[24])
            dat32.append(alist[25])
            dat33.append(alist[26])
            dat34.append(alist[27])
            dat35.append(alist[28])
            dat36.append(alist[29])
            dat37.append(alist[30])
            dat38.append(AF_ESP)
            dat39.append(AF_EXAC)
            dat40.append(AF_TGP)

# Creating DF from lists
df1 = []
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(dat1,dat2,dat3,dat4,dat5,dat6,dat7,dat8,dat9,dat10,dat11,dat12,dat13,dat14,dat15,dat16,dat17,dat18,dat19,dat20,dat21,dat22,dat23,dat24,dat25,dat26,dat27,dat28,dat29,dat30,dat31,dat32,dat33,dat34,dat35,dat36,dat37,dat38,dat39,dat40)), columns = ['alleleID','Type','Name','HGVSName','ProteinChange','OMIM','UniProt','HGMD','HBVAR','GeneID','GeneSymbol','HGNC_ID','ClinicalSignificance','ClinSigSimple','LastEvaluated',"RS# (dbSNP)",'nsv/esv (dbVar)','RCVaccession','PhenotypeIDS','PhenotypeList','Origin','OriginSimple','Assembly','ChromosomeAccession','Chromosome','Start','Stop','ReferenceAllele','AlternateAllele','Cytogenetic','ReviewStatus','NumberSubmitters','Guidelines','TestedInGTR','OtherIDs','SubmitterCategories','VariationID','AF_ESP','AF_EXAC','AF_TGP'])
```

Comment: There is no loop? Is possible share complete code? Because `np.where` working very fast obviously.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: hmmm, I think it is [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @jezrael, there is a loop which is for reading file line by line.. I pasted the code above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I finally was able to speed up this program and brought it down from 19hrs to around 5 hrs just by replacing the np.where with df.loc.
Here is the replaced code:

```
df.loc[df['alleleID'].isin([a1[0]]), 'info'].values
```

There are numerous ways to implement df.loc search/filter but what is interesting or surprising is that in the internet all of them gives example of value being passed as string (eg: like '9879' or 'hosting'). Something like this, where I have to search 15072 in the df.

```
df.loc[df['alleleID'] == '15072']
```

Now, this works fine, but my problem is that I am reading values from another file so I have values in a variable, so I tried as below:

```
var = 15072
df.loc[df['alleleID'] == var]
```

Now, this one does not work and gives error for some reason.

So, I explored more and did some hack and used a list with just one value. As below:

```
list_a = []
list_a = ['15072']
df.loc[df['alleleID'].isin([list_a[0]]), 'info'].values
```

This finally worked and improved a lot from 19 hrs to 5 hrs.